# Select all beans where member variable condition is true

Tags: java, jpa, objectdb

I would like to print out all `Person` objects where `isFoo == true`. I do not know how to complete the below code though for `PersonServlet`

**Person**

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Boolean foo;
    private Boolean fooBar;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Boolean foo, Boolean fooBar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Boolean foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public Boolean getFooBar() {
        return fooBar;
    }

    public void setFooBar(Boolean fooBar) {
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }

}
```

**PersonServlet**

```
public void printAllFoo() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute("emf");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery q = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> c = q.from(Person.class);
    q.select(c);
    ParameterExpression<Boolean> foo = cb.parameter(Boolean.class); //Should this be = true instead?
    ParameterExpression<Boolean> fooBar = cb.parameter(Boolean.class); //Should this be = false instead?
    q.where(
            cb.equal(c.get("foo"), cb.literal(true)),
            cb.equal(c.get("fooBar"), cb.literal(true))
    );
    TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter(foo, true);
    query.setParameter(fooBar, false);
    List<Person> fooPersons = query.getResultList();
    System.out.println("fooPersons: " + fooPersons);
}
```

What is currently being printed out is:

`fooPersons: []`

Even though there are many entries in the database:

> ```
> web.application.bean.Person@50d420eb
> web.application.bean.Person@16bd4dc2
> web.application.bean.Person@663c0737
> web.application.bean.Person@6efde050
> web.application.bean.Person@5d91dd1d
> web.application.bean.Person@134bcae9
> web.application.bean.Person@54f690e4
> web.application.bean.Person@7a29450
> web.application.bean.Person@42b7141a
> web.application.bean.Person@188d92e
> web.application.bean.Person@3f6a5bcb
> web.application.bean.Person@5fb08cf3
> web.application.bean.Person@3ff5d699
> web.application.bean.Person@24dbf79d
> web.application.bean.Person@655d7752
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
  TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(q);
  query.setParameter(foo, true);
  query.setParameter(fooBar, false);
  List<Person> fooPersons = query.getResultList();
```

The parameters can be replaced by literals, e.g.:

```
  cb.equal(c.get("isFoo"), cb.literal(true));
```

Comment: I've updated my code to the above but all that gets printed out is: `fooPersons: []`

Comment: Maybe there are no instances with foo == true and fooBar == false?

Comment: Yes, I was getting the wrong parameter in the servlet. Rookie mistake. Thank you.